# Capture value from an input with svelte

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

I'm trying to capture the `value` of an input using the svelte framework

```
<script>
   var name = document.getElementById("#name");
   var valueName = name.value;

   function showName(){
       console.log(valueName);
   }
</script>

<main>
    <div>
        <input id="name" type="text"">
        <button type="submit" on:click={showName}>Send</button>
    </div>
</main>
```

When initializing the local environment I already get the following error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')

Visual Studio Code marks the code snippet `.value` when I try to capture the input value with the error:

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

What is the correct way to capture the value typed in an input with Svelte ?

Comment: Svelte has a [great tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/) i would recommend doing first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are generally not supposed to query the DOM when using Svelte
2. It is not safe to access the DOM until the component has been mounted (the elements will not exist yet)

You should use [`bind:this`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-bind-this) when you need a DOM element, it will usually be available in DOM events and in the [`onMount`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-onmount) lifecycle function. In general, directly accessing the DOM should be avoided.

In this case you can just [`bind`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-bind-property) the `value`:

```html
<script>
   let valueName;

   function showName() {
       console.log(valueName);
   }
</script>

<input id="name" type="text" bind:value={valueName}>
<button type="submit" on:click={showName}>Send</button>
```